# Grabbing associationType in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I was reading the Sequelize documentation and I am trying to figure out how to get the associationType of a model. It seems like you should be able to import a model (e.g. Posts) and call `Posts.associationType` or `Posts.association.associationType`. [Docs on Associations](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/associations/base.js~Association.html)

I also found an old stack overflow question which mentioned that calling something like `Posts instanceof sequelize.Association.BelongsTo` should work as well. When I call Posts.associations it only gives me the association as a key and value. `{'Comments': 'Comments}`

But neither method works. I seem to be able to access the rest of the model's attributes perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only seeing the `toString()` version of the output. It is more clear if you try:

```js
console.log(Object.keys(models.Posts.associations));
```

This will give you an array of the *keys* of the associations, so you can use them to access more details:

```js
console.log(Object.keys(models.Posts.associations.Comments));
```

You will then see that it has an `associationType` property which you can use to get the string value you are looking for. `Comments` is the name/key for the association which can be overridden with the `as` attribute in the definition.

```js
// type = "BelongsTo"
var type = models.Posts.associations.Comments.associationType;
```